# How do you prove that a solution to the 0-1 knapsack problem is optimal?

Tags: optimization, discrete-mathematics, knapsack-problems

Given a boolean vector b representing a solution to the knapsack problem with n elements k capacity and where each element has integer weight and value.

Proving that the solution is a solution is trivial. You add all the weights multiplied by the selection coefficient and check if it adds to more than the capacity.

But how do I verify that the solution given is *optimal*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, not efficiently (unless P=NP).

Suppose there was a polynomial-time algorithm $A$ to check whether a given solution is optimal.

Then there would be a polynomial-time algorithm to solve the knapsack decision problem, i.e., given a problem instance and a value $V$, check whether there exists any solution with value $>V$.  Here is how: you add a single extra element with value $V$ and weight equal to the capacity; this then gives a trivial solution of value $V$; and now you run $A$ on this modified problem instance.  If $A$ says "not optimal", then there exists a solution of value $>V$ to the original instance; otherwise, there does not.

This would also imply that there exists a polynomial-time algorithm to find the optimal solution for a knapsack problem.  Here is how: you use binary search on $V$, and apply the algorithm for the decision problem in each iteration of binary search.

That would imply that $P=NP$.

So if there exists a polynomial-time algorithm to check optimality, we obtain a proof that $P=NP$.  Conversely, if we assume $P \ne NP$, then there does not exist any polynomial-time algorithm to check optimality.

Comment: So what you are saying is, when someone answers my question we can go collect a turing award.

Comment: @Makogan, nice way to put it!  I like your optimism :)

Comment: However there should be a pseudo polynomial verifier if the sizes of the integers are small, no?

Comment: @Makogan, yes, you can just solve the knapsack problem from scratch to find its optimal solution in pseudo polynomial time.